# ExtrudeGeometry with diagonal line

Tags: three.js

I have created an ExtrudeGeometry Object used the three.js lib,code bellow:

```
   var extrudeSettings = {};
   extrudeSettings.bevelEnabled = false;
   extrudeSettings.bevelSegments = 0;
   extrudeSettings.steps =2;
   //create a shape
   var rectShape;
   ......
   //add the shape to scene
   var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);
   var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: color,wireframe:true }));
   mesh.position.set(100, 100, 0 );
   mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
   mesh.scale.set(s, s, s);
   scene.add(mesh);
```

If I set the wireframe property true,the diagonal line of the object will show,how can I avoid it.Are there some property I should set?thanks!

Comment: You might consider generating your extruded geometry and then using the resulting vertices to develop a custom path to draw a `THREE.Line`, rather than drawing the mesh as a wireframe. I don't think there's an easy way not to draw specific edges

Comment: Glad to receive you comment! So, do you have any idea about how to draw specific edges?Thanks!

Comment: First of all, meshes consist of triangles. The "diagonal" line you are desccribing is just the edge between two triangles, so to say. 
You can somehow take all the vertices you need and generate a new Three.Line object from them (see three.js examples for help). Although generating 1 quad from 2 triangles to get rid of the diagonal lines for arbitrary meshes is not that easy, i think.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me， take all the vertices you need and generate a new Three.Line object.So I have solved my problem!